# How to create array of objects - Go?

Tags: go

I am working in `Go` and `MongoDB` and having the following MongoDB schema

```
[   
  {
    "name":"sample",
    "time": "2014-04-05",
    "Qty":3
  },
  {
   "name":"sample",
   "time": "2014-04-05",
   "Qty":3
  }
]
```

I had tried using the following code to create the above document

```
elements := make([3]map[string]string)
elements["name"] = "karthick"
elements["date"] = "2014-04-05"
elements["qty"] = 3

fmt.Println(elements)
```

But it is not working.

```
Error : cannot make type [3]map[string]string
```

Any suggestion will be grateful

Comment: It's probably worth reading up on slices and deciding first if you really want to use an array or should actually be using a slice: http://blog.golang.org/slices

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a difference between arrays and slices. Arrays are compile time objects while slices are runtime objects. Arrays therefore have more information to offer to the compiler than slices (e.g. length).

In your code, you attempt to create an array of `map[string]string` with 3 elements. You can do this like this:

```
maps := [3]map[string]string{
    make(map[string]string),
    make(map[string]string),
    make(map[string]string),
}
```

You *must* call make for each map, otherwise the maps would be uninitialized (nil).

You can also create a slice with 3 (uninitialized) elements with make:

```
maps := make([]map[string]string, 3)
```

In this case you'd have to iterate over `maps` and initialize each element with `make`.

The simplest solution, in case you're using [mgo](http://labix.org/mgo) would be to create a struct for your data:

```
type Item struct {
    Name string `bson:name`
    Date string `bson:date`
    Qty int `bson:qty`
}
```

and use it in your array:

```
var items [3]*Item
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to achieve? You mixed syntax for creating array and map.

[Here](http://play.golang.org/p/hYYhjbugzE) is working example.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    elements := make(map[string]interface{})
    elements["name"] = "karthick"
    elements["date"] = "2014-04-05"
    elements["qty"] = 3

    fmt.Println(elements)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Above code will create only object. My doubt is how to create array of object as mentioned in the question.

Comment: so @nemo answer is better or you can keep array of maps but I have no idea how it will work with mongo